# Usage of the word "latest"

Tags: adverbs, subcontinental-english

Raj has breakfast almost always before 7:45 AM. On rare occasions, he has after 7:45 AM, but never after 8:00 AM. So If he says "I always have my breakfast latest by 8:00 AM" to convey this fact, is Raj's usage correct?

Comment: Depends...what variety of English does Raj speak? In General American English it doesn't sound right, he would say '...breakfast __at the latest__ by...'

Comment: I have heard this usage in India. Probably, the "at the" is ignored.

Comment: We have a tag "Indian English" ... should that be added here?  It would be "incorrect" of us to say that Raj is incorrect, if Raj is in India...

Comment: This is incorrect in American English, but I know I've heard it. I was going to say it sounded British, but Barrie's answer seems to say it's not used in the U.K. From the comments, it sounds like this is Indian English. I'm guessing that it (like *prepone*) is widely used there, and so should be presumed to be correct for Indian English.

Comment: This is not correct in educated circles in India. Probably it is OK for an Indian family learning to talk in English amongst themselves!

Comment: You seem to ask if it is correct to use *latest* in the sense 'not later than' as against 'most recent'.

Answer (score 8):

*By eight o'clock at the latest* would be the usual way to put it.

Comment: In BrE, would  '...at latest...' be an acceptable alternative?

Comment: @Mitch: It might be found in some regional dialects, but not  in British Standard English.

Answer (score 0):

The question is about the use of  the word *latest* in the particular sense of *not later than*.

According to the answers here, **YES**, *latest* in this sense is used in the US, in the UK, in India, and possibly elsewhere.

All other issues are out of the scope of the OP's question.